# URL Scheme for Phone Call

Tags: url, url-scheme, phone-call, tel

Much like the "mailto" URL prefix launches the user's default mail program and starts a new email with specified address, is there a similar URL scheme that would initiate a phone call? Perhaps "phone," "call," or "sip"?

Incidentally, I'm targeting a platform that is using Cisco CUPS, so there may be a platform-specific way for me to initiate a call that is particular to Cisco, but I thought I'd ask the more general question first. However if anyone knows specifically how to programmatically initiate a call via CUPS, that would be great too.

Answer (score 108):

The official standard for providing a telephone number as a URI is here: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3966.txt

It basically says use `tel:` as the prefix, and start the number with `+[international dialling code]` before the number itself. You can put non-numeric characters as separators (e.g. -) but they must be ignored. So a London (UK) number might be:

```
tel:+44-20-8123-4567
```

A New York (US) number:

```
tel:+1-212-555-1234
```

Comment: tel:number also works, but e.g. on Firefox short numbers are recognized as ports.

Comment: @Nux Do you mean something like tel:123 (which should call the speaking clock in the UK) will be interpreted as http://tel:123/. I'd call that a bug in firefox.

Answer (score 14):

There is such a URI scheme: `tel`. It has an elaborate syntax, but here is a simple example of its usage:

```
tel:123-4567
```

For the full specification, refer to http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3966.txt .

Answer (score 10):

I'm after the same sort of functionality for Microsoft Office Communicator. After a bit of investigation I found that the following URI syntax will initiate a (VoIP) phone call via communicator:

```
tel:+number
```

eg: to get communicator to call my extension:

```
tel:+7780
```

Comment: `tel:+7780` specifies a globally unique telephone number, including country code, of `7780`. I believe country code `7` is Russia, so that's "Russia 780". I find it unlikely that this is globally unique. If you want to specify a local-context phone number, you have to omit the `+` *and* specify a context. If you want to use `+`, then the phone number specified *must* be fully specified and globally unique. See RFC 3966.

Answer (score 7):

`sip:` (or `sips:`) is the [official URI scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme#Official_IANA-registered_schemes) for SIP, and I think `callto:` was used by Skype, but is deprecated.

Comment: "Callto" was discarded because URI schemes locate a resource and do not specify an action to be taken.

Comment: SIP is deprecated because tel: is more general.

Comment: skype://myskypename worked for me