# android sip api SipProfile builder probleme

Tags: android, uri, sip, profile, parseexception

hi am working on android sip api i have a problem with creating profile.
i have tested 2 methodes :
1)

```
try {

        SipProfile.Builder builder = new SipProfile.Builder("sip:165@40.134.279.145");
        builder.setPassword("******");
        builder.setPort(5060);           
        me = builder.build();

        manager.open(me);

    } catch (ParseException pe) {
        Log.d("error", "connexion error");
    } 

   catch (SipException se) {
        Log.d("profile", "error");
    }
```

2)

```
try {

        SipProfile.Builder builder = new SipProfile.Builder(username,domaine);
        builder.setPassword("******");
        builder.setPort(5060);           
        me = builder.build();

        manager.open(me);

    } catch (ParseException pe) {
        Log.d("error", "connexion error");
    } 

   catch (SipException se) {
        Log.d("profile", "error");
    }
```

==> with the first methode i get a NullPointer exception in Open(me) // me is the variable of the profile

==> with the seconde one i have a parseException however the user name and the domaine are good and tested with a softphone Draytek.

notes : am testing on a device with 4.0 android version and i added permissions to manifest.

Answer (score 1):

Please provide full stack traces of the exception you're catching. Also, have you tried integrating the port into the URI, I.E. "sip:165@40.134.279.145:5060"?

Valid SIP URIs are discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5263360/how-to-create-a-link-that-will-dial-a-sip-address-on-a-voip-application-on-an-ip).