# Tel numbers not handled on IOS Emulator

Tags: ios, cordova, tel

I'm working on a phonegap based app for IOS which is already done for Android. I have the following link on a html page:

```
<a href="tel:0180123456789">0180123456789</a>
```

The Android devices are interpreting it correctly.
If I click on this link on the iPhone Emulator in XCode, the console gives me the following feedback:

> Failed to load webpage with error: The URL can't be shown

Is this just because of the Emulator? I'm not yet able to test this on a real device, that's why it is impossible to check it for me right now.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This seems to be an issue with the simulator. I get the same error as you do when I run this in the simulator, but on the device it works perfectly.

Comment: cheers for the approval! saves me a lot of time not to worry about this anymore.

Answer (score 2):

According to [the Apple URL Scheme Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/PhoneLinks/PhoneLinks.html):

> If the Phone application is not installed on the device, opening a tel
>   URL displays an appropriate warning message to the user.

Install it in a device and your click to call link will work, if there is no other issues.