# How to add a phone number to a web page (html markup for phone numbers)?

Tags: windows-phone-7, phone-number

What is the best practice to add a phone number on a web page?
It should be possible to call the number directly from mobile browsers and there should be no false links for desktop browsers.

Problems I am facing:

- Windows Phone does not understand plain text (+123 456 789)
- Desktop browsers IE6-9, Safari, Opera redirect from a tel link (a href="tel:+123 456 789")
- Windows Phone does nothing when adding onclick="return false"

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to mark-up phone numbers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164004/how-to-mark-up-phone-numbers)

Answer (score 1):

I generally use something like this:

```
<input onclick="window.location.href='tel:0000000000'"></input>
```

I tested this on multiple Windows Phone devices and it works just fine. Google uses this in their mobile version of the Maps website, when you try to lookup a place that is nearby to a specific location.