# How to make a phone number callable on mobile devices in newsletters?

Tags: newsletter, electronic-direct-mail

These are the various options that i have tried using table structure for newsletters. My problem is that on the click of the phone number on mobile devices and it redirects to a new page having the callto or tel in its url, whereas in browsers it redirects to a blank page. Help me out on this.

```
<a href="tel:9865551555">9865551555</a>
<a href="callto:9865551555">9865551555</a>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164004/how-to-mark-up-phone-numbers

Comment: Smart phone devices automatically detect the number and we get the option to call the number or save the number as contact, but here I want the devices to detect the number in a newsletter(EDM's) and give the user the option to call the number. Tel and callto doesn't solve this problem as it redirects to a new page with the number in its url. The phone devices gives the pop up saying request server cannot be found. I hope my question is clear.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to include the country code. The format found in [this tutorial](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/quick-tip-make-telephone-numbers-do-something--webdesign-9271) worked well for me.

```
<a href="tel:+19865551555">(986) 555-5155</a>
```

Comment: How to make dynamic numbers, I'm getting from backend callable?