# SEO - How to Show Phone Numbers in Google Search

Tags: seo, search-engine

when I search for a keyword in Google, the listing for my site has 2 phone number in the result.

[image: search result with a phone number]

I want to know why Google shows these numbers? (These numbers are not in my main text.) How can I add phone numbers in Google results? (What quality should they have?)

Comment: see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164004/how-to-mark-up-phone-numbers

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Google (and other Search Engines) uses [Schema](http://schema.org/), which is a markup for HTML defining structured content (which the phone number is). So if you want to get your telephone number to appear a good way to go about this will be by including structured data. For [example](http://schema.org/docs/gs.html)

```
    <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/LocalBusiness">
        <span itemprop="telephone"><a href="tel:01234555666">Link Text Here</a></span>
    </div>
```

If you are going to use phone number I strongly recommend your take advantage of all of the possibilities such as Address, Reviews, Maps, Logo and so on. Full Local Business [schema's here](http://schema.org/LocalBusiness).

There are other ways of achieving this sort of effect, for example, to get your picture next to a authored post you would add a link somewhere in the page going to a Google+ Profile like this

```
<a href="https://plus.google.com/your_profile_id/?rel=author">Tim Baker</a>
```

Google also has a [very handy tool](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets) which tests your site to see if it can find structured data - definitely worth using to make sure you implement properly and of course [webmaster tools](http://www.google.com/webmasters/) has bits to it as well.

Comment: Hi guys, does this still apply with the current updates to Google search? I've added a bunch of details as structured data however I still cannot see the phone number in google search results. am I missing something?