# Call now button for mobile website

Tags: wordpress

I've installed wordpress call now button plugin and activate it with phone number but not appear on any screen of mobile website.
If any one know any other plugin for this purpose i.e to place a call now button or image and user is able to call with his mobile carrier when clicked. 
Also the shortcut code for this plugin when we want to add it in a template file i really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<a href="tel:32334242323">Call Me</a>
```

You might need to use `callto:` instead of `tel:` sometimes.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11143507/1370034) uses jQuery to replace `tel:` by `callto:`:

```
if (!jQuery.browser.mobile) {
    jQuery('body').on('click', 'a[href^="tel:"]', function() {
            jQuery(this).attr('href', 
                jQuery(this).attr('href').replace(/^tel:/, 'callto:'));
    });
}
```

You should note that the above snippet was posted in June 2012. The `jQuery.browser` property has been removed as from jQuery 1.9 and is now available in the Migrate Plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Use `tel:888-888-8888`

source: [How to mark-up phone numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164004/how-to-mark-up-phone-numbers)

All you have to do is put it in your html. That should get you started.