# ASP.NET MVC - Mobile button to make a call

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mobile

I'm working on mobile project using asp.net mvc4 and I would like to have a button that allows to make a call on smartphones, how to create such button?

Comment: There are many similar questions, check [How to mark-up phone numbers?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1164004/944681)

Answer (score 0):

Usually, a link that allows to call from smartphone is looks like that :

```
<a href="tel:+33242125212">Call</a>
```

If you want buttons, you can add a button class to make it look like a button.