# how to customize Standard Salesforce Page

Tags: salesforce, visualforce

I got a requirement to customize the contacts objects Standard view page, i need to create a hyperlink to phone number field. Is it possible to do this ? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. You have to make a page using VisualForce.

First and foremost take a look of the [official doc](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Visualforce) to how to make it.

I suppose your link should trigger a call, If so it should be something like this: `<a href="tel:{!contact.phone}"> {!contact.phone}</a>`

The page should be like this:

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact">
   <apex:pageBlock title="Simple Title">
      <b>Call <i>{!$User.FirstName}</i>. <a href="tel:{!contact.phone}"> {!contact.phone}</a></b>
   </apex:pageBlock>
   <apex:detail subject="{!Contact.Id}" relatedList="false" />
</apex:page>
```

Comment: I need to create a new VisualForce page and overriding the Standard view page with new VisualForce page do you mean that ?

Comment: Yes indeed. But its depends how you need to display that phone link

Comment: There is any possibility to customize the Standard view page other than overriding it with the new VF page.

Comment: Yes, you can change the contact page layout, adding or removing buttons or fields. But, you are not able there to include a link using a field value. So, it's depends your your requirement

Comment: I have one more questions martin what is 'tel' which you have written in the Achor tag.

Comment: this is a good answer to your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164004/how-to-mark-up-phone-numbers

Comment: Hi martin, how can I append Achor tag to a phone number while rendering the contact details?

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a hyperlink to the phone number via a formula (text) field. We did this to allow a "click to dial" functionality from Chrome to Lync as there is not a plugin for this.

Clicking the formula link will dial out the phone number in whichever application is registered for making phone calls on the computer.

```
HYPERLINK("tel:" & Phone, Phone, "_self")
```