# "tel:+18475555555" link does nothing when clicked on mobile devices

Tags: html, mobile, tel

So, I wanted to make the phone number of my site click-able so I used the below syntax:

```
<div class="col-md-8">
...
<h3>
<a href="tel:+18475555555">1-847-555-5555</a>
</h3>
...
</div>
```

When I click this phone number from my desktop's firefox browser it asks me whether I have to open it with Skype.

However, when I click on it from my mobile (tried both Android Galaxy S3 and an iPhone 5), nothing happens. How do I trouble shoot this?

I am using http://www.themenesia.com/themeforest/truehost/ theme, if that helps.

Comment: Have you tried it without the + sign?

Comment: Yep, I did... just now. Still the number is not clickable on the iPhone :(

Comment: @BhavaniKannan Are you trying to use the US Country Code of `+1`?

Comment: @BhavaniKannan Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17219688/href-tel-and-mobile-numbers?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drop the + in front of the number.

```
<a href="tel:18475555555">1-847-555-5555</a>
```

It's not required and should not affect how a desktop browser handles it.

EDIT:

I now found that you need to either drop the country code (in this case the 1 for US), and/or separate the actual number with dashes:

```
<a href="tel:1-847-555-5555">1-847-555-5555</a>
<a href="tel:8475555555">1-847-555-5555</a>
```

Comment: Very minor change, but I think it should be _affect_ instead of _effect_.

Comment: Yes indeed. Good on you for the grammar check! :D

Comment: Yes I just now tried without a + and still nothing happens when I tap on it from a mobile phone :(