# Can a HTML telephone link accept spaces in the value?

Tags: html

Is there anything wrong or problematic with including spaces as well as a `plus` symbol (for the international code) in a telephone link? Example:

`<a href="tel:+46 000 00 00 00">+46 000 00 00 00</a>`

(I replaced the actual number I want to use with 0s here)

Comment: why you need  space in telephone number link ?

Comment: there is a full description here in another question.
http://stackoverflow.com/q/17219688/7744547

Comment: It's supplied this way by my client website' setup

Answer (score 28, accepted):

HTML is irrelevant here. A URL is a URL no matter where you put it.

The [relevant spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3966) says:

> even though ITU-T E.123 [E.123] recommends the use of
> space characters as visual separators in printed telephone numbers,
> "tel" URIs MUST NOT use spaces in visual separators to avoid
> excessive escaping.

So "**no**".

Even if a space was allowed, the general rules for URLs would mean that you would have to replace it with `%20` (hence the comment about excessive escaping).

Answer (score 4):

Yes it is incorrect to add spaces in telephone numbers on `href`, according to [RFC 3966](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3966) (The tel URI for Telephone Numbers):

> **5.1.1. Separators in Phone Numbers**
>
> Phone numbers MAY contain visual separators. Visual separators
> ('visual-separator') merely aid readability and are not used for URI
> comparison or placing a call ... **"tel" URIs MUST NOT use spaces in
> visual separators** ...

As you can see, the RFC clearly states: ***"tel" URIs MUST NOT use spaces in visual separators***.

Comment: This is an older, but still relevant question and it's now 2020. Whether compliant with the spec not, a phone number with spaces formatted as a tel: link appears to work with Chrome. I expect the chrome dev team have coded this in, to allow for input errors, just as with certain other malformed html snippets. I have not tested with other modern browsers and it would be interesting know if this is the same.