# href tel: scheme not working in WKWebView iOS Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, tel

I am trying to wrap my website inside a `WKWebView` but an anchor with href="tel:312133" is not showing any action when clicked on it.

```
import UIKit
import WebKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet var webView: WKWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }



    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        let mUrl = URL(string: "https://www.example.com")
        let mRequest = URLRequest(url: mUrl!)
        webView.load(mRequest)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Comment: Did you try this on a device, or just in the simulator?

Comment: hello, can you provide please complete source code with anchor?

Comment: i tried it in simulator and real device as well.

Comment: Please check if the answer here is suffient. It depicts that telephone numbers need to satisfy a certain format to be detected: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17219688/href-tel-and-mobile-numbers?rq=1