# Ionic App crashes in iOS

Tags: android, ios, angular, ionic-framework

I developed my first app, an Ionic/Angular app, and it works fine on Android. The app is already published in the Google Play Store. Now I've built an IPA for iOS and at first, it seemed working fine. The splash screen was shown and I got redirected to the Home Page. But I am encountering the following issues:

The app crashes when I
**1.** Click on an input field (when it opens the keypad), 
**2.** Or when I reopen the app after using
 `onclick="window.open('tel:+000000000', '_system')"`
or
`onclick="window.open('mailto:mail@mail.nl', '_system')"`
or
when I just click on the iOs home button and reopen the app.

```
Date/Time:           2018-05-21 17:14:53.5359 +0200
Launch Time:         2018-05-21 17:14:47.9337 +0200
OS Version:          iPhone OS 11.3.1 (15E302)
Baseband Version:    2.03.12
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
abort() called

Filtered syslog:
None found

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x1816f2d8c __exceptionPreprocess + 228
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x1808ac5ec objc_exception_throw + 55
2   CoreFoundation                  0x181700098 -[NSObject+ 1388696 (NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 139
3   UIKit                           0x18b7a6de4 -[UIResponder doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 291
4   CoreFoundation                  0x1816f85c8 ___forwarding___ + 1379
5   CoreFoundation                  0x1815de41c _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 91
6   Duofor                          0x102e63e2c 0x102e40000 + 146988
7   Duofor                          0x102e63c24 0x102e40000 + 146468
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x180fe4ae4 _dispatch_client_callout + 15
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x180fecf18 _dispatch_continuation_pop$VARIANT$mp + 423
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x180ff6808 _dispatch_source_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 1363
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x180ff15b8 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$mp + 715
12  CoreFoundation                  0x18169b070 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 11
13  CoreFoundation                  0x181698bc8 __CFRunLoopRun + 2271
14  CoreFoundation                  0x1815b8da8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 551
15  GraphicsServices                0x18359b020 GSEventRunModal + 99
16  UIKit                           0x18b59978c UIApplicationMain + 235
17  Duofor                          0x102e464ac 0x102e40000 + 25772
18  libdyld.dylib                   0x181049fc0 start + 3
```

Comment: Is there anything on the device's log?

Comment: @ChristianBenseler thank you for your reply. I edited my post with the device's log

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17219688/href-tel-and-mobile-numbers

Comment: @Gurbela thank you for the reply, but this has nothing to do with my issue.