# Href tag tel: not working

Tags: html

I know this question has been asked lot of times. But I don't find a solution for my problem.

I have a link like which I want to make an externall call from mobile view like this:

```
<a href="tel:902 1111 111">902 111 111</a>
```

But when I click on it, it's not working. 
I'm using: *Java ee*, *HTML*, *CSS* to build my page. Any idea on why it's not working?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17219688/href-tel-and-mobile-numbers?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa did not help ?

Comment: Do you have any click event handler which might be preventing the expected behavior?

Comment: @Hearner nop :( did see the link but didn't make it work. I'm gonna check (only in case) what @K K says...

Comment: @KK you were right... I have a handler that is preventing my click to happen... Thanks... It could have been hours...

Comment: @Sonhja That's Great!

Comment: @KK Could you write an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: You can try removing a space in number <a href="tel:9021111111">902 111 111</a>

Comment: @Sonhja Answer added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue can be related to a click event handler which might be preventing the default behaviour of the link. For example, `return:false` in the end of the handler might be preventing this behaviour. Try checking that and remove it. This should fix the problem.