# HTML anchor tel tag formating

Tags: html, tags, anchor, href

I have a small question about the anchor tel: tag in HTML.

Is this valid, or are there any standards on how to write it properly?

```
<a href="tel:+358 50 11 22 33"></a>
```

It has bugged me about the spaces and the prefix, are they allowed?

Comment: this could help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17219688/href-tel-and-mobile-numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standards pretty much say that you can't have spaces. So this:

```
<a href="tel:+358 50 11 22 33"></a>
```

Is valid HTML.

Comment: @Krullmizter if my answer solved your problem, you can mark it as accepted by clicking the grayed out tick mark to make it filled green and show that this answer fixed your problem.