# Find phone number in string with PHP and make it clicklable to call

Tags: php, laravel

I have a text which contains a phone number. I want to find this phone number and turn it to a clickable link, so that people can simply click on it and call the number.

Example:

> If you are interested please call us on +XXXXXXXXXX

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to use a Regex to find the number inside the text and then you can simply replace it with with an anchor tag which has the href attribute as `href="tel:+XXXXXXXX"`.

Here you can find the info about the anchor tag: [href="tel:" and mobile numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17219688/href-tel-and-mobile-numbers)