# mailto: link equivalent for phone calls?

Tags: html

Is there any way using html and/or JS to link an image so that it makes a phone call. Similar to the mailto: links. This would just make life a lot easier if this was possible. Say if a person had skype, could a button then open skype for them and call a number?

Thanks in advance

Comment: try callto:, skype: or tel: - and see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164004/how-to-mark-up-phone-numbers (tel: being the defacto standard now)

Answer (score 81, accepted):

like this:

```
<a href="tel:+1800229933">Call us free!</a>
```

you can look also on this article

[add-telephone-number-links-with-html](http://www.paulund.co.uk/add-telephone-number-links-with-html5)

Answer (score 4):

Presuming  that desktop userd use skype,

```
Call <a href="<? echo ($detect->isMobile()) ? 'tel' : 'callto'; ?> :+1-579-827-0034">579-827-0034</a>
```