# Auto Call - Redirect Page

Tags: html, redirect, phone-call

Example: I post a link on Facebook. (URL) 
When someone click on that link it opens the number on their dial screen. 
Thus no click to call button on the page. 
The page when loaded automatically add details to dial screen. 
Auto dial screen redirect

Comment: *this function: <a href="tel:0815526065">Calling</a>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mailto: link equivalent for phone calls?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24349340/mailto-link-equivalent-for-phone-calls)

Comment: basically the page must do what the click to call function does without any clicking taking place.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using an a tag .

```
<a href="tel:+91 9496******">Call us at +91 9496******</a>
```