# Make phone number clickable in PHP request table results

Tags: php, html-table

I have a table with data issued from a PHP request, I want to make phone numbers clickable to allow passing a call if used with mobile device, and if possible to make the whole cell clickable.

My actual PHP code is:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr>";

    echo "<td align='center'>" .$row['name']. "</td>";      
    echo "<td align='center'>" .$row['phone']. "</td>";

echo "</tr>";

  }
  echo "</table>";
```

Comment: should try researching issues like this yourself first. This is not hard to find information in a web search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to insert an anchor tag

inside the link you can use the `tel:` or `callto:` to use the auto dial functions
more info in [How to mark-up phone numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164004/how-to-mark-up-phone-numbers)

for you code

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr>";

    echo "<td align='center'>" .$row['name']. "</td>";      
    echo "<td align='center'><a href='tel:" . $row['phone'] . "'>" .$row['phone']. "</a></td>";

echo "</tr>";

  }
  echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Placing an anchor around a td isn't valid HTML. A better solution is to link the text (phone number) inside the td. If needed you can add `display:block; width: 100%;` to the anchor.

Comment: ah my bad, i didnt focus much on where im putting the anchor :) Ill do an edit