# Unable to make phone number clickable (Rails app using CoffeeScript)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, coffeescript

I'm running a restaurant discovery website, where users see a bunch of markers on a map, they click on a marker and that opens up an infoWindow in which the user can see meta details for the restaurant.

The problem: i'm trying to make restaurant phone number clickable. When I view the output, in HTML, I see a clickable link, but instead of seeing the phone number in that link, I see my variable name instead (screenshot attached). And when I click on the link, I get an error message (screenshot attached).

See attached code - the relevant CoffeeScript file and the HTML view being rendered.

**MAIN.COFFEE FILE**

```
infoHTML = (data) ->
  img = if data.photo then "<img onerror='this.parentNode.removeChild(this)' src='#{data.photo}' style='margin:5px 5px 0 0;max-height:70px'>" else ''
  html = "<table><tr><td style='vertical-align:top'>#{img}</td><td>"
  html += data.name + '<br>'
  html += data.address + '<br>'
  html += "<a href= '+ data.phone + '> + data.phone</a>" + '<br>' if data.phone
  html += "<img src='/assets/uber.jpg' style='max-height:13px'> £#{data.cost}" + '<br>' if data.cost
  if data.michelin_status && data.michelin_status != 'yes'
    html += data.michelin_status + '<br>'
  html += data.rating + '% rated' if data.rating
  html + '</td></tr></table>'
```

---

**VIEW BEING RENDERED**

[image]

---

**WHAT I SEE WHEN I CLICK ON THE PHONE LINK**

[image]

Comment: You have a mix of ' and " on that line.  Looks like you need a '  before the "

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have mixed you quotes, so instead of

```
html += "<a href= '+ data.phone + '> + data.phone</a>" + '<br>' if data.phone
```

Use

```
html += "<a href= '"+ data.phone + "'>" + data.phone + "</a><br>" if data.phone
```

Also, check [How to mark-up phone numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164004/how-to-mark-up-phone-numbers)

---

Update - with the `tel:` prefix:

```
html += "<a href= 'tel:"+ data.phone + "'>" + data.phone + "</a><br>" if data.phone
```

Comment: Doesn't work. With your fix, I now see the number in the view, but if I click on the number I get an Action Controller exception message saying Routing Error - no route matches.

Comment: That's how it's supposed to work because you're adding that phone number to the href, so you get, for example, `<a href="123-4567-89">123-4567-89</a>"`, which will look for that route that doesn't exist. I've added the additional link to my answer and check it to see how do you make a clickable phone number (I believe you need to add the `tel:` prefix - `<a href="tel: 123-4567-89">123-4567-89</a>"`).