# Multi-Function jQuery onClick to Call Script

Tags: javascript, jquery

Having done a lot of research and testing, I've pieced together several snippets to achieve almost 100%, thanks to multiple Stack articles (such as [How to Click to show & Click to call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41750706/how-to-click-to-show-click-to-call)).

Given multiple containers as shown:

```html
<div class="entry-details">
    <p class="phone">+18885551212,,,111</p>
    <p class="address">111 Any Street, Anytown, NY 10010, USA</p>
    <p class="time">11:00 to 08:00</p>
</div>

<div class="entry-details">
    <p class="phone">+18885551212,,,222</p>
    <p class="address">222 Any Street, Anytown, NY 10010, USA</p>
    <p class="time">11:00 to 08:00</p>
</div>

<div class="entry-details">
    <p class="phone">+18885551212,,,333</p>
    <p class="address">333 Any Street, Anytown, NY 10010, USA</p>
    <p class="time">11:00 to 08:00</p>
</div>

<div class="entry-details">
    <p class="phone">+16665551200</p>
    <p class="address">444 Any Street, Anytown, NY 10010, USA</p>
    <p class="time">11:00 to 08:00</p>
</div>
```

The goal onClick is to:

1. Copy p.phone field text to href;
2. Wrap p.phone field with href tel tag ;
3. Replace p.phone content with "Click to Call";
4. On click, show number formatted as # + ext (ex. 888-555-1212 Ext 222) if commas and extension are present, standard tel if not (ex. 888-555-1212).
5. and finally, dial the # including pauses (commas);

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $('.phone').wrapInner('<a class="phone-link" href=""></a>');
        $('.phone').each(function() {
            var $phoneLink = $(this).find('.phone-link');
            var _linkUrl = $phoneLink.text();
            $(this).find('a.phone-link').attr('href', 'tel:' + _linkUrl).text('Click to Call');
        });

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="entry-details">
    <p class="phone">+18885551212,,,111</p>
    <p class="address">111 Any Street, Anytown, NY 10010, USA</p>
    <p class="time">11:00 to 08:00</p>
</div>

<div class="entry-details">
    <p class="phone">+18885551212,,,222</p>
    <p class="address">222 Any Street, Anytown, NY 10010, USA</p>
    <p class="time">11:00 to 08:00</p>
</div>

<div class="entry-details">
    <p class="phone">+18885551212,,,333</p>
    <p class="address">333 Any Street, Anytown, NY 10010, USA</p>
    <p class="time">11:00 to 08:00</p>
</div>

<div class="entry-details">
    <p class="phone">+16665551200</p>
    <p class="address">444 Any Street, Anytown, NY 10010, USA</p>
    <p class="time">11:00 to 08:00</p>
</div>
```

I had written another function for the final piece (changing Click to Call on click), but

1. It didn’t work
2. It changed all instances of .phone when clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have replaced all .phone on click, because you used a global selector. Try bind event to each link, or you can use live listener on .phone-link selector.

```
jQuery(function($) {

  var formatPhone = function(tel) {
    // format should be here
    return tel;
  }

  // replace in a single loop
  // without wrapping
  $('.phone').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var tel = $this.text();
    var $link = $('<a class="phone-link" href="tel:'+tel+'">Click to Call</a>')
      .on('click', function(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        $(this).text(formatPhone(tel));
      });

    $this.empty().append($link);
  });
});
```

sample with a live listener

```
$(document).on('click', '.phone-link', function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.text(formatPhone( $this.attr('href') ));
});
```

Comment: Thanks @i.Nemiro! Using the first example, it does almost everything except changes ,,,111 with Ext 111, and does not dial when clicked on neither the first or second click. I am attempting to implement the live listener solution.

Comment: For the record, this solution produced the desired behavior sans the dial prompt ,which is prevented by ev.preventDefault() in the on.click function. Remove that & viola!

Now, I need to display the resulting contents of a.phone-link on click and replace one or more instances of the comma with the string "Ext " so that 888-555-1212,,,111 dials as such, but displays as 888-555-1212 Ext 111.

I tried this jQuery/Regex line in various parts of the function but its not working:, $(this).match("/,+/").replace("/,+/", "Ext "); I also tried $this.match...

I suck at this, but I'm learning.

Answer (score 0):

I was a bit confused about the intended switch between "Click to Call" and "actual Phone number". Please let me know if it serves the purpose or needs some more changes

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $(".phone").on("click",function(event){
          if(!$(event.target).hasClass("phone-link") ){
            var phoneLink = $(this).text();
            $(this).wrapInner('<a class="phone-link" href=""></a>');
            $(this).find("a.phone-link").attr('href','tel:' + phoneLink).text('Click to Call');
          }
        
        });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="entry-details">
    <p class="phone">+18885551212,,,111</p>
    <p class="address">111 Any Street, Anytown, NY 10010, USA</p>
    <p class="time">11:00 to 08:00</p>
</div>

<div class="entry-details">
    <p class="phone">+18885551212,,,222</p>
    <p class="address">222 Any Street, Anytown, NY 10010, USA</p>
    <p class="time">11:00 to 08:00</p>
</div>

<div class="entry-details">
    <p class="phone">+18885551212,,,333</p>
    <p class="address">333 Any Street, Anytown, NY 10010, USA</p>
    <p class="time">11:00 to 08:00</p>
</div>

<div class="entry-details">
    <p class="phone">+16665551200</p>
    <p class="address">444 Any Street, Anytown, NY 10010, USA</p>
    <p class="time">11:00 to 08:00</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Arpit!@iNemiro actually nailed it the first go, with a minor modification. I appreciate your input!