# Telephone number not clickable

Tags: html, css

In my markup, I have included a phone number that I want to be clickable. 
This is my code -

```
<h3 class="footer">Need help? Call <a href="tel:+180006XXXX">1800 06X XXX</a></h3>
```

When I run this code I see two red brackets around the phone number with a small chain like icon that says "invalid link". The number is not clickable.

Please help!

Comment: Which browser did you try that on? I tried it on `chrome` + `mac` and it prompted me with `facetime`.

Comment: This is working fine for me in chrome, looks like it's correctly formatted

Comment: Is anything [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164004/how-to-mark-up-phone-numbers) of here to you?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That should be

```
<a href="tel://+180006XXXX">1800 06X XXX</a>
```

note the `//`...

Comment: why the  downvote? That's how phone links work. I am talking about a link that can be clicked on a *smartphone* to directly dial the number. Try it if you don't believe it!

Comment: This actually worked. But I don't know why. @Johannes Could you please explain?

Comment: just because that's the way a phone link is written... (compare to `http://...` for weblinks, where you also need these slashes)

Comment: Are you really sure? According to 2.7.1 of [RFC 7230 on the `http` URI scheme](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230) the double forward slash is mandatory. The slashes are not mentioned by a single word in [RFC 3966 on the `tel` URI scheme](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3966)

Comment: @Johannes wrong! `Phone: Let’s not forget that the primary purpose of a mobile phone is to call people! This can be smoothly integrated into your website by using the little known tel: protocol. Just like you use a mailto: to link to an email address, you use tel: to link to a phone number. When you click the tel: link it causes the phone to dial **<a href="tel:5121234567">Phone 5121234567 to book a table</a>**`

[w3c](https://www.w3.org/wiki/Introduction_to_mobile_web)

Comment: @agrm I haven't read either of these, but I have used it that way on websites where it works.

Comment: @dippas maybe you should try it. And if the OP says it works now, it can't be that wrong, hm?

Comment: @Johannes even more agmr said as well `tel:` protocol doesn't take`//` like `mailto:` doesn't too

Comment: @Johannes I wasn't aware `tel://` was even a thing. Out of curiosity, do you have any information on devices/browsers accepting `tel://` and not `tel:`?