# Phone number links open blank page in Chrome on Samsung Galaxy S8

Tags: html, google-chrome, samsung-galaxy

I am working on a site with a "Call Us" link. Tapping on this link in a mobile device should call the phone number in the link.

For some reason, in Chrome on a Samsung Galaxy S8, tapping on the link opens a blank new page in the web browser instead of calling the number.

Here is the code:

```
<a 
  href="tel:+1888-888-8888"
  rel="noopener noreferrer" 
  alt="Phone number"
>
    888-888-8888
</a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue on some android devices, if you have a `target="_blank"`, it'll open in a new tab and not register the `tel:` link. If you specify `target="_self"` it'll open in the phone's default calling app. See the updated code below.

```
<a
  href="tel:+1888-888-8888"
  rel="noopener noreferrer" 
  alt="Phone number"
  target="_self"
>
    888-888-8888
</a>
```

Comment: Or, since `_self` is the [default](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#target), one could omit the target attribute.

Answer (score -1):

Try "callto:" scheme.
This seems to be a more common option.

Comment: No.  `tel:` is standardized.  See also:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/1467262/362536