# how to show an address and phone as a link in polymer

Tags: polymer

I'm trying to show and address and a phone in a website using polymer, but i was trying to show in the phone as a link when you press the link show something like a call, and to show the address when you click in the address and open a map with the address.
There is any element that allow me do that?

### Element code:

```
<dom-module id="my-aboutuscomment">
<template>
    <style>
        :host {
            display: block;
            @apply(--layout-vertical);
        }
        .div-general{
            width: 350px;
            height: auto;
            padding: 0 16px 0 16px;
            margin-top: 16px;
        }
        .div-list-general{
            margin-left: 16px;
            @apply(--layout-vertical);
        }
        .div-list{
            margin-left: 16px;
            @apply(--layout-vertical);
            padding: 16px 16px 16px 16px;
            font-family: 'Roboto', 'Noto', sans-serif;
            font-size: 14px;
            line-height: 24px;
        }
    </style>
    <div class="div-general">
        <h2>About us</h2>
        <div class="div-list-general">
            <span>SignaSafe Inc.</span>
            <span>We are a company with a few years of work in the software development business. We are comminment with our customers to offer a good customer service and a high quality software product to help your business grow and expand.<span>
            <div class="div-list">
                <span>
                    <iron-icon icon="room"></iron-icon>
                    Address:{{sscontact.address}}
                </span> 
                <span>
                    <iron-icon icon="perm-phone-msg"></iron-icon>
                    Telephone:{{sscontact.telephone}}
                </span> 
                <span>
                    <iron-icon icon="markunread-mailbox"></iron-icon>
                    Mail:{{sscontact.mail}}
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    Polymer({
        is: 'my-aboutuscomment',
        properties: {
          sscontact: {
            type: Object,
            value: function() { return {
                address: "204 Plymouth Ave, Syracuse NY-13211",
                telephone: "3155302019",
                mail: "signasafe@gmail.com"
            }; }
          }
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Check out [google-map](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/google-map) for the map element.

Comment: thank you Kayce but I'm no looking exactly to show a map, I'm looking to emulate the same behavior that occur in the mobile application that allow you to tap in a phone label or in an address and show the option that correspond, is there any element in polymer that allow that?

Comment: For a telephone call you can use `tel:` as prefix followed by `+[international dialling code]` and then the desired number ([source](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009181/url-scheme-for-phone-call))

Comment: Perfect that is what I mean, thanks