# How do I hyperlink a phone number?

Tags: html, href

I am trying to hyperlink a number (international phone number) on my HTML webpage.

I've looked at tons of other examples online, and mine looks exactly the same so I'm not sure why it's not working :(

```
<a href="tel:+44 20 7123 4567">+44 20 7123 4567</a>
```

and here is my error message

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6mqeU.png)

Comment: I hope that's not your real number?

Comment: what in the world is that a screenshot of??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [URL Scheme for Phone Call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009181/url-scheme-for-phone-call)

Comment: @Progman It is not a duplicate because the OP knows it's `tel:` but is having issues with encoding.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [href="tel:" and mobile numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17219688/href-tel-and-mobile-numbers)

Comment: Although it's not technically allowed, that link works fine for me on more than one device.  Seems like more of an issue with the UI you're trying to type it into

Answer (score 6):

HREF links can’t contain spaces.

So your code will look like:

```
<a href="tel:+442071234567">+44 20 7123 4567</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hyperlinks (the URI in `href=""`) cannot contain spaces. Fortunately E.123 and E.164 (the international phone number standards) do not require spaces or formatting characters either.

You have two options:

1. Use URI-encoded spaces `%20`:

   ```
   <a href="tel:+44%2020%207123%204567">+44 20 7123 4567</a>
   ```
2. Remove spaces:

   ```
   <a href="tel:+442071234567">+44 20 7123 4567</a>
   ```

I prefer #2 because it makes it easier to see the real digits because `%20` contains digits.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the space between the numbers in your html. For example: `<a href="tel:+442071234567">+44 20 7123 4567</a>`.