# Click to call phone number?

Tags: html, hyperlink

How do I create a phone number in my app that I can click on so that it opens directly in my phone and I can then call it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I hyperlink a phone number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53270766/how-do-i-hyperlink-a-phone-number)

Comment: This question has nothing to do with React.

Comment: I want an answer that has something to do with React? One that was given to me elsewhere, to use Link from React Router Dom.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the anchor element in this way:

```
<a href="tel:555-555-5555"><img src="path/to/phone/icon.jpg" alt="Call 555-555-5555" /></a>
```

most modern browsers support this.

Duplicate of this: [How to trigger a phone call when clicking a link in a web page on mobile phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1608548/how-to-trigger-a-phone-call-when-clicking-a-link-in-a-web-page-on-mobile-phone)

Comment: Answers should not be reposted. Please flag the question as a duplicate or make a comment to that effect.

Comment: @isherwood uh, I was looking for an answer using React, why change the name and tags for my post? Now that I've talked with a friend of mine they suggested I use Link from React router dom.

Answer (score 0):

you can implant it same as you did in html!

```
<a href="tel:PHONE"> Call! </a>
```